How to translate 'The Order Protects' in Latin?
Google translate gives me 'ordo tuetur', but I am wondering if it is the best possible translation? The word 'order' in the phrase refers to a military-religious order like the Knights Templar or the Teutonic Knights. The word protect would then refer to protecting in the sense of military protection, or acting as a shield, or the like.

The "best possible translation" is always a matter of debate, but the question here should rather be whether Google Translate produced gibberish as usual, or whether it's acceptable Latin. Incredibly, even though you gave it a fragment of unidiomatic English – no offence, but that is exactly the type of input that tends to confuse Google Translate even more than it usually is – it happens to have produced a perfectly good translation that can probably not be greatly improved upon.

Ordo is the common word for religious orders (military or not), including the Knights Templar, who are called Ordo Pauperum Commilitonum Christi Templi Hierosolymitani (OPCCTH).
tueri does indeed mean "protect," as in, "shield from danger," and is a common word. The variant tutari (i.e., ordo tutatur) would also be entirely appropriate in this context. You could also say protego (to shield), which is the source of English protect.


Thank you very much for your answer. Would you say that there is a meaningful difference between the phrases 'Ordo defendit', 'Ordo tuetur', and 'Ordo tutatur'? e.g., would any of these be more suitable for a motto than the others?
